# Probability with birthdays in a specific time range

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Out of a group of 71 people, how many of them would have a birthday through July 16th- July 31st? I'm not looking for just one persons probability in the group of having their birthday during that time, more like an overall probability. I have the probability of one person having their birthday during that time, which is 2.12%, but that doesn't tell me about the other 70 people.

Comment: You might ask about the probability that at least one of them had a birthday in that range. Or you could ask about the *expected* number of them that have a birthday in that range. (The expected number may not be an integer!) Or you could ask about the *most likely* number of people with a birthday in that range (the "mode"). Do you know the way to calculate any of these?

Comment: Also, half a month should be around $4\%$ of the year, not $2\%$.

Comment: This range is $\frac {16}{365}$ of all the birthdays so you expect $\frac{16}{365}$ of the people to be in that range.  So you expect $71\times \frac {16}{365}$ people to have birthdays in that range.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the people's birthdays are independent and uniformly distributed throughout the year, then the number of birthdays can be modeled as a Binomial random variable
$$X \sim \text{Binomial}(71,(31-15)/365).$$

The expected value and variance of this random variable are
$$E[X] = 71 \cdot \frac{16}{365} \approx 3.11$$
$$\text{Var}(X) = 71 \cdot \frac{16}{365} \cdot \frac{350}{365} \approx 2.98,$$
so we should expect to have the number of birthdays to be in the range $3.11 \pm \sqrt {2.98}$ with high probability (68%).

Comment: Simulation suggests $3\pm 2$ at $86.7\%$

Comment: You could add some statistics about twins, but that would depend on the situation. In a school class you would have quite a few twins.